# Does a forked process in Ruby on Rails have a max execution time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

We're running a Rails application which can starts cli commands. The cli commands are like daemons, they should run until they are stopped.

We start them using:

```
pid = fork do
  exec "/path/to/cli"
end

Process.detach(pid)
```

We're using Puma as application server.

The problem is that the forked processes stop after a period. Is this caused by a max. execution time set in Ruby on Rails or Puma for forked processes?

Comment: Do you have any diagnostics from the stopped processes? I expect this is not anything like a max execution time, but an error condition in the cli. You could try running the cli stand-alone on a terminal to see if the same behaviour manifests. But it could also be something that only occurs in the detached process - perhaps the cli expects to have a resource such as TTY, and fails when it cannot access it.